# Должен ли я высвободить память аргументов командной строки?

Tags: c++, c

Редко я работаю с аргументами командной строки из программы на C/С++. Подскажите, должен ли я высвобождать массив `char *argv[]` `delete[]`'ом, который пришел в качестве параметра в функцию main или этим займется система?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {...}
```

P.S. мне бы хотелось узнать точно, как делать правильно.

Вообще мысли такие - раз не я отводил память, то и не мне ее освобождать. (Вольная интерпретация концепции, когда отведение и высвобождение должно производиться на одном уровне абстракции в коде)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Нет, высвобождать не надо. Действует простое правило: кто выделил - тот и высвобождает.
В данном же случае main() получает указатель на участок памяти, выделенный до того.

Answer (score 3):

Нет, вы ничего не должны высвобождать.